# Linux glib needs pkg-config and pkg-config needs glib?

Tags: linux, glib, pkg-config

I try to install udev. And udev gives me an error during the `./configure`

```
--exists: command not found configure: error:
pkg-config and "glib-2.0 >= 2.16" not found, please set GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS
to the correct values or pass --with-internal-glib to configure
```

Ok,  pkg-config and glib-2.0 is missing.

At first I tried to install pkg-config. I got this message:

```
checking whether to list both direct and indirect dependencies... no
checking for Win32... no
checking if internal glib should be used... no
checking for pkg-config... no
./configure: line 13557: --exists: command not found
configure: error: pkg-config and "glib-2.0 >= 2.16" not found,
please set GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS to the correct values or 
pass --with-internal-glib to configure
```

Ok I interpret, that glib is missing.

Next step installing Glib.

And I got this message:

```
configure: error: in `/root/glib-2.33.3':
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBFFI_CFLAGS
and LIBFFI_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

But I'm puzzled now. 
Do they need each other?
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you have already observed, there is indeed a circular dependency between pkg-config and glib. To break it, pkg-config's [source code](http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.27.tar.gz) includes a version of glib, which is enough to compile it. This should break the dependency cycle.

Try configuring pkg-config with `--with-internal-glib`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That worked, but the error messages of glib and udev still remained

Comment: @Peter have you tried compiling `udev` with `./configure --with-internal-glib`?

Comment: @Peter absolutely try that. I can't stress enough how important it is to read error messages carefully and understand what they mean!

Comment: Nice try: `./configure --with-internal-glib configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-internal-glib`

Comment: pkg-config is installed now. But the next think appeared during config udev. I read the error message carefully. And I think I understood what the error is nearly, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is the error message: `error: Package requirements (usbutils >= 0.82) were not met:
No package 'usbutils' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables USBUTILS_CFLAGS
and USBUTILS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.`

Comment: I don't have any USB on my board so I don't want to install that usbutils. What is the value I should set the environment variables? to install udev, finally.

Comment: @Peter You need to provide `udev` with a `usb.ids` file, otherwise it won't compile. Check the `--with-usb-ids-path=DIR` configure option.

Comment: @ user12 : Thanks for the Answer. Should I replace DIR with a real path? If I don't do that I get this message: `error: pci.ids not found, try --with-pci-ids-path=` Where do I get the path of .ids files? Thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: if I try to feed the `./configure` with DIR dummies like that `./configure --with-pci-ids-path=DIR --with-usb-ids-path=DIR` I got another error `error: libacl not found
`

Comment: `udev` is a pretty central daemon with lots of dependencies. On Ubuntu it looks like this: `libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-5), libc6 (>= 2.10), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0), libselinux1 (>= 1.32), upstart-job, libudev0 (>= 175), module-init-tools (>= 3.2.1-0ubuntu3), initramfs-tools (>= 0.92bubuntu63), procps, adduser, util-linux (>> 2.15~rc2), upstart (>= 1.4-0ubuntu6)`

Answer (score 8):

It is already contained on the glib error message:

> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBFFI_CFLAGS
>   and LIBFFI_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
>   See the pkg-config man page for more details.

The Glib build script uses pkg-config to find libffi. But you can provide the information also manually, by setting environment variables. Then the call to pkg-config is not necessary. Glib itself does not need pkg-config at all.

Another solution to the problem is provided by the pkg-config people. Again, at the end of the error message:

> please set GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS to the correct values **or 
>   pass --with-internal-glib to configure**

In this scenario, pkg-config itself is packaged with everything necessary to build without having Glib on your system already.

Comment: If you don't know how to do the first solution, doing the second solution is a no-brainer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That worked with the second way, but the error messages of glib and udev still remained

Answer (score 1):

```
export GLIB_CFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)" 
export GLIB_LIBS="$(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)"
printf '# In the case of a RHEL6.5\n\tGLIB_CFLAGS=%s\n\tGLIB_LIBS=%s\n' "$GLIB_CFLAGS" "$GLIB_LIBS"
# In the case of a RHEL6.5
        GLIB_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include
        GLIB_LIBS=-lglib-2.0

# _now_ it is a no-brainer.
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

libudev is now part of systemd and it doesn't depend on glib.

Most Linux distributions provide binaries for pkg-config, libudev, and glib.  They are probably installed already, but if not, you can use the package manager to get them.

If you do need to compile this stuff yourself, consider using [pkgconf](https://github.com/pkgconf/pkgconf), a light-weight implementation of the pkg-config that does not use glib.